# How to randomly select an Excel cell from a column?

Tags: python, excel

I'm trying to randomly select an individual cell from a column of an Excel worksheet in Tkinter. I have tried a few different ways:

1st, I tried:

```
wb = load_workbook('Test_Workbook.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

range = ws['A2':'A7']

for cell in range:
    for x in cell:
        print(random.choices((x.value)))
```

2nd, I tried

```
wb = load_workbook('Test_Workbook.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

A = ws['A']
print(A)
for cell in A:
    print(random.choices(f'{cell.value}') )
```

Both examples output random letters of a string inside the cells instead of picking a random cell from the column. How would I get it to return the value of a random individual cell?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to achive this and I try to stick close to your appoaches.
So the first thing to see is, that to call a cell in the `worksheet` object, you do so using the A1 notation e.g. `ws["B5"]`.
If the range you want to select from now is `A2:A7` you would need a list such as

```
l = ['A1','A2',..'A7']
rand_cell = random.choice(l)
```

Now to automate this a little, you can do something like the following:

```
column = 'A'
row_range = list(range(2,8)) # [1,2,...7]
```

and select a random value from row_range and concatenate the two

```
rand_cell = "{column}{row}".format(column = column, row = random.choice(row_range))
```

Full example:

```
wb = load_workbook('Test_Workbook.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

column = 'A'
row_range = list(range(2,8)) # [1,2,...7]

rand_cell = "{column}{row}".format(column = column, row = random.choice(row_range))

print(ws[rand_cell])
```